# Dictionary python to href urls

Tags: python, flask

```
tvseries = {
    'NFL': ['Monday June 3', 'Tuesday June 4'],
    'NHL': ['Monday April 13', 'Friday April 23']
}
```

I have a dictionary that I pass to a jinja template. This is rendered on a flask web app.

```
<body> {% extends "template.html" %} {% block content %} {% for key, value in myDictionary.items() %}
    <ul>
        <div class="container2"><b>{{ key }}</b></div>
        <div class="container3">{{ value }} </div>
    </ul> {% endfor %} {% endblock %} </body>
```

How would I make every value that is printed out be a href that searches google for *Key + Value*.

For example when I click on 'Monday June 3' beside NFL, I want to search google for **"NFL Monday June 3"**

Comment: you can use something like ```<a href="https://google.com/search?q={{ key }} {{ value }}">click me</a>```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't think it would be that straightforward.